# How to delete post from table row using ajax for asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement a delete function for posts. I'm showing all the posts in a table. I can't seem to find a better way to show all the post.

This is the html:

```
<table border="1" id="show__posts" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Post Id</th>
            <th>Post</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

**JQuery code for loading posts**

```
var loadposts=function(){
        $.ajax({
        
        url:"http://localhost:12091/api/post/",
        crossdomain: true,
        method:"GET",
        complete:function(xmlhttp,status){
            if(xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var data=xmlhttp.responseJSON;
                $("#msg").html(data[0]);
                console.log(data[0]);

                var str='';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            str += "<tr>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].UserId+"</td>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].PostId+"</td>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].Post1+"</td>";
                            str += "<td><button 
                            onclick='deletepost("+data[i].PostId+")'>Delete me</button></td>";
                            str += "</tr>";
                }
                $("#show__posts tbody").html(str);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#msg").html(xmlhttp.status+":"+xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
    }
    });
}
loadposts();
```

**Incomplete JQuery Code for Delete Post**

```
var deletepost=function(){
    $.ajax({
        
        url:"http://localhost:12091/api/post/"+deleteid,     <--how should I get this id from the table?
        method: "DELETE",
        header:"Content-Type:application/json",
        data:post,
        complete:function(xmlhttp, status){
            if(xmlhttp.status == 204)
            {
                alert("Post Deleted");
            }
            else{
                console.log(xmlhttp.status+":"+xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Finally my **Code in controller**

```
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        postRepository.Delete(id);
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

**Now my questions:**

1. Is there a better way to show posts in webpage except table? I need to show user id, post id, post
2. how should I get the post ID from html and use it to delete the post?

**

**Update:**
I've completed the delete function like suggested:

```
var deletepost=function(deleteid){
    $.ajax({
        
        url:"http://localhost:12091/api/post/"+deleteid,
        method: "DELETE",
        header:"Content-Type:application/json",
        data:deleteid,
        complete:function(xmlhttp, status){
            if(xmlhttp.status == 204)
            {
                alert("Post Deleted");
            }
            else{
                console.log(xmlhttp.status+":"+xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: deletepost is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tables are a long debate and depends on framework you are using. In bootstrap they use it : [Bootstrap tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)
2. You just need to add your id in you delete function :

```
var deletepost=function(deleteid){
...
}
```

Then add a column to your table for displaying a delete button :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    str += "<td>"+data[i].UserId+"</td>";
    str += "<td>"+data[i].PostId+"</td>";
    str += "<td>"+data[i].Post1+"</td>";
    str += "<td>";
    str += "<button onclick='deletepost("+data[i].PostId+")'>Delete me</button>";
    str += "</td>";
    str += "</tr>";
}
```

3. You shouldn't use complete method but sucess and error. Complete is for executing code in both case.

```
$.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            box.html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            box.html("Sorry.");
        }

    });
```

Comment: hey I've updated my code as per your suggestion. Can you please suggest a fix for the new problem I'm facing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/tfeb8z45/1/
It works fine. Check your delete function is at the right place (accessible).